# why the profile inside the state return null instead of empty object after update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with my redux reducer.It doesn't return  the expected state after dispatching the getCurrentProfile action, it returns the initial state which is "null" instead of "{}", which is fetched with an ajax request, so when the network return the result the state profile change to the result returned but when it is an error returned it stay null instead of empty object, so that is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krxN5.png)

```
profileAcction.js :

import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_LOADING, CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE} from './types';

//Loading profile
const setProfileLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: PROFILE_LOADING
  }
};

// Clear current profile

export const clearCurrentProfile = () => {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE,
  
  }
}

// Get current profile
export const getCurrentProfile = () => dispatch => {
dispatch(setProfileLoading());
  axios.get('/api/profile')
  .then(res => dispatch({
    type: GET_PROFILE,
    payload: res.data 
  })).catch(error =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: {}
    }))
  };

profileReducer.js:

import {GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_LOADING, CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  profile: null,
  profiles: null,
  loading: false
};

 const profileReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PROFILE_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
      case GET_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: action.payload,
        loading: false
      }
     
      case CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE:
        return {
          ...state,
          profile: null,
          loading: false
        }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default profileReducer;
```

Comment: Because `res.data` is `null`

Comment: no res.data is not null, when i had profile it return me the profile

Comment: but when i had an error it return me null instead of "{}"